# Is there any way to import csv that has column name as dates into oracle?

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus

I try to use oracle sql developer tool and it shows an error. And cant import columns with date as column name.is there any way to import this data set into oracle.

[Error shows in sql devaloper tool]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y80Yb.png

Comment: Seems to be the same assignment [as this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11383441/kalana).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date (or similar) can't be used as column name in Oracle:

```
SQL> create table test (27/3/2020 number);
create table test (27/3/2020 number)
                   *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

But, if you enclose it into double quotes, then it works:

```
SQL> create table test ("27/3/2020" number);

Table created.

SQL>
```

However, the fact that you *can* do it doesn't mean that you *should* do it. I suggest not.

More info about [Schema Object Naming Rules](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm).

Besides, date value should be one of columns within the table, not the column itself. Data model you want is bad, don't do that.